# Find large files in a batch script and move it to a different folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need a batch script equivalent to this powershell code. I wrote this powershell script but I don't know how to write it to a batch script. Please help!  this is really frustrating me.  How do i search for large files and and when I find it, I need to move it to a different folder.

```
$Message = "FOUND HUGE FILES!!!"
$AlertType = "Error" 
$ComputerName = "server1"

gci D:\files | where {$_.length -gt 50mb} |
foreach-object {

move-item -path $_.fullname -destination "D:\folder"

Write-eventlog -logname Application -Source Application -eventID 1009 -entrytype Information -Message $Message 

}
```

Comment: Batch math can only resolve files up to 2 GB `(2^31 - 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
set message=FOUND HUGE FILES!!!
Set alerttype=Error
Set computername=server1

Pushd d:\files
For %%a in (*) do (
  If %%~za GTR 50000000 (
     Move "%%a" d:\folder
Eventcreate /ID 1009 /L APPLICATION /T INFORMATION /SO information /D "%message%"
  )
)
Popd
```

Comment: Just commenting that this will fail on files larger than 2 GB.